# Handling Airplane Mode with HTTP Requests

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-post, airplane-mode

My app has quite a few occasions where it makes HTTP post requests. I discovered during testing that if the user is in airplane mode when this request is made, the app crashes. So, in an effort to handle this situation elegantly, I call a function that tests whether the phone is in airplane mode immediately prior to making the `AsyncTask` call. If the function returns true, I don't make the `AsyncTask` call.

The test itself works correctly. The user is notified that they must turn off airplane mode and them come back and try again. The problem is that after airplane mode is turned off, and the `AsyncTask` proceeds, my HTTP post crashes the app. If airplane mode was never on in the first place, everything runs smoothly.

I can't figure out what to do. Is there a better way to test for airplane mode in the first place? Or is there something else that I need to do after blocking the `AsyncTask` to restore the system state such that the http request will succeed.

Any advice is appreciated. Here is some code to hopefully make this more clear. If there is additional code that will help, please let me know. Thanks!

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

            context = this;

            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions(context);
                if (userFunction.isAirplaneModeOn(context)) {
                    userFunction.warnAboutAirplaneMode(context);
                    return;
                }

                new Login().execute();  

            });
    }

    class Login extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        private JSONObject json;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            String URL = context.getResources().getString(R.string.dbURL) + context.getResources().getString(R.string.attemptLogin_php);

                    //this next line is the one that crashes - iff the user was
                    // previously in airplane mode. If there weren't ever in airplane
                    // mode, this runs just fine
            json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, params);

                    ...

    }
}
```

Here is the UserFunctions class:

```
    public class UserFunctions {

            @SuppressLint( "NewApi" )
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {

                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
                    return Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                       Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
                } else {
                    return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                           Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
                }

            }

            public void warnAboutAirplaneMode(Context context) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle("Airplane Mode Is On")
                    .setIcon(R.raw.airplane_mode)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setMessage("Your phone is in airplane mode. Please turn this off then try again.")

                    .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }

                    });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();   
            }

        }
```

Comment: Isn't this more of a no-network issue? A user can still enable Wifi in airplane mode. If I understand the problem correctly, you probably should be checking if any network connectivity is available.

Comment: Good point. I think you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking for `Airplane mode` alone is probably not a good idea because you can have wifi on in airplane mode. But there are probably a few possible answers to this but what I do is register a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens for network state changes with the following permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

my receiver looks like this in the manifest

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.NetworkReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

when that gets fired I check to see if there is network connection or not and keep an app wide boolean in `SharedPreferences` and I check that boolean every time right before I make a HTTP call.

I have found instances where this could still not completely solve your problem such as `SocketTimeOutExceptions` where the user has bad reception and the connection times out.

Comment: This seems like a good idea. I'm having trouble getting the NetworkReceiver to fire. I'm concerned that this might not fire for airplane mode changes. Also, it might not solve the underlying problem that while I'm able to trap changes in network connectivity, once a connection is reestablished, the http post op comes back as null. I'll try this out and post back. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Thanks very much for this idea. I've marked it as the answer, but I need to comment on this for the benefit of others who might come across it. The problem with this approach is that I'm finding that it takes upwards of a minute before the broadcast receiver is notified of the connectivity change, which leaves a possibility that a user could go offline, but then invoke a network operation before the broadcast receiver updates the shared preference. In that case, a null pointer exception can occur, so I still need to deal with that scenario. If you have any advice, I'd love to hear it. Thanks!

Comment: The time it takes for the broadcastreceiver is phone dependent, on my galaxy nexus it fires in seconds but on an older phone like the droid x2 it can take up to a minute like you are seeing

Comment: I've been working with some other approaches (that don't use broadcast receivers) to see if I can speed things up, and I'm getting the exact same delays. I have a brand new phone, so the delay seems not to be just about the age or the o/s version. So, I agree, your solution is as good as it seems to get. The rest is up to the user's phone. Thanks again for your help.